# opencv,node.js and android communication

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, opencv

I have developed a program which detects human in real time(webcam) and displays it to the webpage of the local network. This is done by creating a server and websockets using Node.js and opencv.

Now, I have to develop an android app where i should get a notification everytime when the human is detected from the webcam video of a local host. How can i achieve this using node.js server and android interfacing?

Any suggestions or inputs with code examples would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ionic to convert between webpages and android. Then use push notifications to alert the user.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this and update you soon.

Comment: You can update and tick the answer, if this answer helped, for now. Spread the love :)